# Trying to create a Parallax effect for all image sizes and element position

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, background-position, background-size

I followed the [Parallax tutorial on Code.tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641) and I also saw some other similar to this. However, none of the tutorials work perfectly for some reason, as there is always some blank space created either at top or at the bottom of the element.

So I decided to change the code to also take the 'background-size' property of the element based on height of the element and the speed of the parallax effect. But still it's also not working correctly and creating blank space at the bottom.

Please check my code and let me know what could be wrong:

```
$('.parallax').each(function(){

    var $el = $(this),
        speed = $el.data('speed'),
        elHeight = $el.outerHeight(),
        wHeight = $(window).height(),
        elOffset = $el.offset().top;

    //Taking into account the amount the background would move and putting that into
    //background-size so there are no white spaces.
    var extraSize = (elHeight*speed)+elHeight;
    var percentage = (extraSize/elHeight)*100;
    $el.css({'background-size': percentage+'%'+' '+percentage+'%'});


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var diff = $(window).scrollTop() + wHeight - elOffset;

        var yPos = -(diff*speed);
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
        $el.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    });
});
```

Also here is the css:

```
.parallax {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1366/500');
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Spacing issue is with the tutorial itself **[DEMO](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html)**

Comment: True, but this code is quite different than that in the tutorial, as I've taken into account element offset and the window height, so the background position should start to change when the top of the element touches the bottom of the window. Also in my code, I'm increasing the background-size property of the element, so it matches the amount the background would move. I mean sure there is some problem in the code, which is what I'm trying to figure out. But it really does fix the issue that was in the tutorial.

Comment: can you show a working fiddle, with the issue?